# Can't select vertices, edges or faces in box select mode

Tags: modeling

I'm learning Blender and I noticed that I can't drag select any edges, vertices or faces using box selection. I noticed that using lasso selection has the same issue.

I created a gif to show the issue.

Could there be some setting that I accidentally turned off, something else I'm missing?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You've most likely changed the [mode](https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/interface/selecting.html#selecting-modes) of *Box Select*. Make sure that either *set* or *extend* is chosen. The options can be found in the header, the *Tool* tab in the sidebar and the *Active Tool and Workspace settings* as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Selection Mode]